# How to continue execution after breakpoint in Matlab 2018?

Tags: matlab, compatibility

I am running Matlab script from external script and doing it by code like this

```
matlab -r dbstop in myfunction; myfunction;
```

In Matlabs 2016 and 2015 it was causing normal interactive debugger stop on breakpoint at first like of `myfunction`. In Matlab 2018 it also stops, but neither editor, nor debug buttons appear available.

How to fix?

Comment: can you use `dbstep` and `dbcont`?

Comment: @NickyMattsson sometimes I don't have command line (it is posessed by caller)